# Show facebook comment count in Joomla article blog view

Tags: php, facebook, joomla

NOTE : the url I posted here was purposely broken by putting a space after the http:// due to the strict rules of stackoverflow.

If you enter this url

> https:// graph.facebook.com/v2.4/?fields=share{comment_count}&id=http:// kclau.com/investment/where-klci-is-heading/

directly in browser, it displays :

> {    "share": {
>         "comment_count": 3    },    "id": "http:// kclau.com/investment/where-klci-is-heading/" }

Fine. So I prepare the php as follow :

```
<?php 
$url = "http:// kclau.com/investment/where-klci-is-heading/";
$response = file_get_contents("https:// graph.facebook.com/v2.4/?fields=share{comment_count}&id=".$url);
$obj = json_decode($response);
echo $obj->share->comment_count;
?>
```

It display nothing at all.
I tried var_dump($obj) display NULL !!

What's wrong with it ? Can someone help please ? thanks

Comment: i only get the `id` when trying to access on the link you gave

Comment: the full url is this https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/?fields=share{comment_count}&id=http://kclau.com/investment/where-klci-is-heading/ with https in front. Even with only "id", the var_dump result shouldn't be NULL, right ?

Comment: `var_dump($response);`

Comment: var_dump($response) I get nothing, no result.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the previous code not working, but someone had suggested to me the CURL, which is working :-

```
<?php
$url = "http://kclau.com/investment/where-klci-is-heading/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/?fields=share{comment_count}&id=".$url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $obj->share->comment_count;
?>
```